Getting error While updating Angular version 8 to version 9
I am trying to migrate my Angular project from Angular version 8 to version 9.1.13. I couldn't understand this error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (35:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         return this.pColorschemesOptions;
|     }
>     static { this.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.2.3", ngImport: i0
ngImport: i0, type: ThemeService, deps: [], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Injectable }); }     
|     static { this.ɵprov = i0.ɵɵngDeclareInjectable({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.2.3", ngImport3", ngImport: i0, type: ThemeService, providedIn: 'root' }); }

These are my dependencies
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^1.1.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^11.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.48",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.12",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.36",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.13.11",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-material-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.8.0",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.4.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.2",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.12.9",
    "videogular2": "^6.0.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.23",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.55",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }

I'm thinking that the error is regarding the ng2-charts. But I don't what to do now.
I dont have any idea what to do now. Can some one help me out.

@angular/forms and @angular/router are currently at version 8.2.14 in your list.

I tried updating them (@angular/forms & @angular/router)  but still i am facing the same error i mentioned above.
